# How can I convert an int to byte array without the 0x00 bytes?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert an `int` value to a `byte array`, but I'm using the `byte` for MIDI information (meaning that the 0x00 `byte` which is returned when using `GetBytes` acts as a separator) which renders my MIDI information useless.

I would like to convert the `int` to an `array` which leaves out the 0x00 bytes and just contains the bytes which contain actual values. How can I do this?

Comment: Which endian? Big or little? An example input/output would really help us be sure of your intent. With encoding, the specifics matter.

Comment: What I mean is that when I convert int 1 to a byte array I don't want 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 but just 0x01

Comment: This problem description is horribly worded.  Didn't the system you're working with come with any documentation, or are you reverse engineering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info Ben added, this should do what you require:

```
    static byte[] VlqEncode(int value)
    {
        uint uvalue = (uint)value;
        if (uvalue < 128) return new byte[] { (byte)uvalue }; // simplest case
        // calculate length of buffer required
        int len = 0;            
        do {
            len++;
            uvalue >>= 7;
        } while (uvalue != 0);
        // encode (this is untested, following the VQL/Midi/protobuf confusion)
        uvalue = (uint)value;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        for (int offset = len - 1; offset >= 0; offset--)
        {
            buffer[offset] = (byte)(128 | (uvalue & 127)); // only the last 7 bits
            uvalue >>= 7;
        }
        buffer[len - 1] &= 127;
        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe wikipedia is wrong about being the same as the encoding protobuf uses, but this is LSB-first and VLQ is MSB-first.

Comment: @Ben - I can confirm protobuf is always LSB first [source](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html) - so wikipedia may well be wrong; to quote: "Each byte in a varint, except the last byte, has the most significant bit (msb) set – this indicates that there are further bytes to come. The lower 7 bits of each byte are used to store the two's complement representation of the number in groups of 7 bits, **least significant group first**."

Comment: Of course, except for the MSB of the final group, simply reversing the array should fix this...

Comment: @internetmw - this highlights why it is so very important to be **very, very precise** when specifying encoding details...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, quite new to all of this

Comment: @internetmw - note the code *as presented* is protobuf, which is different to Midi. I have corrected wikipedia.

Comment: @internetmw @Ben - revised to encode MSB instead of LSB; untested, though

Answer (score 1):

You've completely misunderstood what you need, but luckily you mentioned MIDI.  You need to use the multi-byte encoding that MIDI defines, which is somewhat similar to UTF-8 in that less than 8 bits of data are placed into each octet, with the remaining providing information about the number of bits used.

See [the description on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity).  Pay close attention to the fact that protobuf uses this encoding, you can probably reuse some of Google's code.

Comment: UTF8 is quite different to the encoding that protobuf uses (and Midi, it seems) - but yes, the protobuf code should work nicely.